# Can you customize the activation highlight color of a SwiftUI context menu?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view with light text on a dark background. I need to add a context menu to it. Here is the code I am using:

```
Text(rowModel.detail)
     .font(detailFont)
     .foregroundColor(Color(/* a light color */))
     .contextMenu {
     Button(action: {
         UIPasteboard.general.string = self.rowModel.detail
     }, label: {
         Text("Copy")
     })
 }
```

When the menu is activated and the device is in light mode, this is the result:

[image: Screenshot of context menu highlighting]

I can find nothing on the web that suggests I can change that highlight color. But just in case, I figured I'd ask here. Can it be done? Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to set a custom highlight state for your button

```swift
struct YourButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

  func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
      .padding()
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.green : Color.blue)
      .cornerRadius(8.0)
  }

}


// To use it
Button(action: {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = self.rowModel.detail
}, label: {
    Text("Copy")
})
.buttonStyle(YourButtonStyle())
```

Comment: This changes the background color even when the button is simply tapped (ie. not held down).